# Something is killing my snakegourd plants

Tags: diagnosis

My plant's leaves are developing yellow, black, and dry spots all over. The flowers are also drying up before becoming the vegetable itself. There are ants nearby but I don't think ants do this type of damage. Could this be fungal?

Comment: Very hard to help without a picture of the plant.  Are you growing it indoors or out?  What part of the world?

Comment: Definitely get us some pictures!!  As well as any more information you could think of!!

Comment: Hi Uthra! We haven't heard from you lately. Do you still need help? If so, let us know! Thanks!